# How to check whether a file is updated after git pull?

Tags: git

for example my scenario is jenkins pulls the code from repository.Then i need to check whether the file package.json file is updated or not.

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking?  What is your actual problem, because we need the situation, not a description of your setup.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't trust that GIT is providing the most up to date file? If not how are you going to use the information that package.json has changed? You could always look at the modification date, but again, I don't know what your intentions are.

Comment: If I understand you want to see with file are updated after a pull. In this case you can use git log --stat

Comment: Please can you help us understand your question?

Comment: Situation is I need to run npm install only when package.json file is updated. So, I need to check whether package.json file is changed after jenkins job pulled the code from repository.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: fetch the remote and compare the changes

- Fetch the repository from the remote using `git fetch origin`.
- Check if there are any changes using `git diff --name-only origin/master package.json`
- pull the changes using `git pull`